# получить значение getItem(position)

Tags: java, android

использую custom simpleadapter, через getItem(position) получаю такую вот строку в лог `I/System.out: {costDiscount=3.57, income=1.57, discount=11}` Для дальнейшей кастомизации списка, нужно иметь возможность получить значение income. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Код адаптера покажите

Comment: В своей реализации адаптера переопределите метод `getItem()` и возвращайте, что считаете нужным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так а в чем проблема? Смотрите в отладчике или в исходниках андройда какого класса объект возвращается через метод getItem у SimpleAdapter'a. Увидите что это наследник Map. Соответственно приводите возвращаемый объект к этому типу и получаете нужное вам значение, как из обычной мапы:

```
((Map<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position)).get("income")
```

Единственное я не уверен к `Map<String, ?>` или `Map<String, Object>` приводить тип, вроде и так и так должно работать, но проверить сейчас не на чем.

Comment: вот как раз в получением значения была проблема, банально не понимал, как получить значение, в итоге родил такую штуку `String str = String.valueOf(getItem(position));str = str.substring(str.indexOf("income=") + 7, str.indexOf("income=") + 11);
        double item = Double.parseDouble(str.replace(",", ""));`